# Toggle multiple buttons individually inside a react table

Tags: reactjs

Inactive State:
[image: Inactive State]

Active State:
[image: Active State]

When I toggle a single button the state of every other button changes which I don't want. Is there any way to control the state of these toggles individually

This is my code for columns to be used in the table:

```
const COLUMNS = useMemo (() => [
      {
    Header: "Username",
    accessor: "Username",
    textAlign: "left",
    sortable: false,
    },
    {
    Header: "Status",
      accessor: "Status",
      textAlign: "center",
      Cell: ({ value, cell: { row } }) => (
        <div>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <IOSSwitch
              checked={status}
              onClick={toggler}
              name="status"
            />
          }
          />
          
          {status ? <span>Active</span> : <span>Inactive</span>}
         
          </div>
      ),
    },
```

This is my code for the table:

```
<Table {...getTableProps()}>
              <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                  <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                      <Th
                        {...column.getHeaderProps({
                          style: { textAlign: column.textAlign },
                        })}
                      >
                        {column.render("Header")}
                      </Th>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </thead>
              <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {page.map((row) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                  return (
                    <Tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                      {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                        return (
                          <Td
                            {...cell.getCellProps({
                              style: { textAlign: cell.column.textAlign },
                            })}
                          >
                            {cell.render("Cell")}
                          </Td>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tbody>
            </Table>
```

Comment: please show your code. Not an image

Comment: I've edited it and pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign each button to its individual state for example you can have three states for three buttons.

your states should look like this:

```
const [firstButton, setFirstButton] = useState(false)
const [secondButton, setSecondButton] = useState(false)
const [thirdButton, setThirdButton] = useState(false)
```

and in your onClicks you should say:

for example for second button:

```
onClick={()=>setSecondButton(false)}
```

and when you want to use this state in your table you should match every button with its state

ps: if your number of buttons are not fix, you should write a function to return an object which keys are button names and values are false ( false is default and this should change when clicks ).

Because of the immutability of states in react.js, you should clone the state and change what you want and leave every other thing as it is then update the whole state.

and use it like:

```
onClick={()=>setButtonsState({...buttonsState, secondButton:false})}
```

where buttonsState is like:

```
const [buttonsState, setButtonsState] = useState(
{
  firstButton: false,
  secondButton: false,
  thirdButton: false
}
)
```

Comment: I'm really new to react and don't know how to apply these kinds of logic (Still learning about states). I've edited the post and pasted the code

Comment: @ShalikhShab where your state changes?